# Getting the total number of records in a single knexjs query when using the limit() method

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I use knexjs and postgresql. Is it possible in knexjs to get the total of records from the same query in which the limit is used?

For example:

```
knex.select().from('project').limit(50)
```

Is it possible to somehow get the total number of records in the same query if there are more than 50?

The question arose due to the fact that my query is much more complex, which uses a lot of subqueries and conditions, and I would not like to make this query twice to get the data in one query and the total number of records (I use the .count() method) from another.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your obscurification manager (knexjs?) but I would think you should be able to add the window version of the count() function to your select list. In plain SQL something like: Where `...` represents your current select list.  (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/OkUcS7gp))

```
select ..., count(*) over() total_rows
  from project 
 limit 5;
```

This works because the window count function counts all rows selected, after all rows selected, but before the `LIMIT` clause is applied. Note: This adds a column to the result set with the same value in every row.